# selectedMessage() is not triggered on message select in simulator with Message Extension

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, msmessage, ios-messages-extension

I am attempting to trigger a message content specific segue on message select with my messages extension. I am using the following function override:

```
    override func didSelect(_ message: MSMessage, conversation: MSConversation) {
    print("selected a message")
    print(conversation.selectedMessage?.url)
}
```

This function logs the selected message in the origin message after sending. However, when I change to the recipient thread in the simulator and select the message, my `didSelect()` override is not triggered.

Additionally, if I return to the origin transcript after this, the `didSelect()` override is not triggered either.

I was under the impression this override should trigger on every message select, regardless of the context.

API Docs: https://developer.apple.com/reference/messages/msmessagesappviewcontroller/1833298-didselect

THANKS ALL!!

Comment: Same issue here.  didSelect and willSelect called on first time only.  After that, i can't detect that the same message was re-selected.  How do i go about doing it.   In my case, i play a video in the app, every time the message is selected.  So if the user plays it once, they can't play it again after that, because no event goes to the message extension.